# If file is found, check if two other files exist then do set of commands

Tags: bash, if-statement, testing

This may be a naive question but I am having trouble formatting and testing options to do what I want. I am having trouble formatting my code down below.

Basically, all three files (`dti_nii_LPS_g_CHECK`, `dti_bvec_LPS_g_CHECK`, and `dti_bval_LPS_g_CHECK`) have to exist at the same time for my code to work.

If all three files are found, then a "Y" will report for the Inventory File (`$INVENTORY_FILE`) that I am writing to (a CSV, with column `DTI_file_found`). This represents a complete data point.

If any one of them are not found, then a "N" will report, because it is not a complete data point.

Is there something I am missing? I've tried replacing the `if` statement with the commented version above that line of when we check if all three files exist, but I wasn't getting the output I was expecting after double checking data points that should report as "N" but report as "Y" in reality from my code when I run it with the option that checks all three.

```
# -- check if files exist (dti) = DTI_file_found
  dti_nii_LPS_g_CHECK="${GO_TIMROBERTS}/${subjid_g}/${subjid_g}_DWI_30dir_LPS.nii.gz"
  dti_bvec_LPS_g_CHECK="${GO_TIMROBERTS}/${subjid_g}/${subjid_g}_DWI_30dir_LPS.bvec"
  dti_bval_LPS_g_CHECK="${GO_TIMROBERTS}/${subjid_g}/${subjid_g}_DWI_30dir_LPS.bval"

  # Check that all three exist?
  # if [[[ -f dti_nii_LPS_g_CHECK && -f dti_bvec_LPS_g_CHECK && -f dti_bval_LPS_g_CHECK ]]];

  if [ -f "$dti_nii_LPS_g_CHECK" ]; then
    echo "$dti_nii_LPS_g_CHECK for $subjid_g exists."
    printf "$dti_LPS_g_CHECK," >> $INVENTORY_FILE
  else
    echo "$dti_LPS_g_CHECK for $subjid_g does not exist."
    dti_LPS_g_CHECK_F="N"
    printf "$dti_LPS_g_CHECK_F," >> $INVENTORY_FILE
  fi
```

Comment: `[[[` ? is that a typo ? , Put a valid shebang and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this to check whether the files corresponding to the filenames in the variables exist

```
# Check that all three exist?
if [[ -f "$dti_nii_LPS_g_CHECK" && -f "$dti_bvec_LPS_g_CHECK" && -f "$dti_bval_LPS_g_CHECK" ]]; then
    ...
fi
```